# Virtualize SAP HANA tables in Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: hana, azure-synapse

Is it possible to virtualize SAP HANA tables in Azure SQL Data Warehouse? If so, please provide link to the documentation or details.

We are currently using Smart Data Access to virtualize tables between HANA tenants and it works well for our scenario. However, Data Warehouse has recently been introduced to our environment and the requirement is to have the data (virtual or replicated) in there as well.

Our current workaround is a script that replicates the data, but now we are having issues with keeping the data in sync. Moreover, we would prefer not to replicate data at all if possible.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to virtualise Hana tables from Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

SAP customers typically export data to Azure storage, then ingest to Azure SQL Data Warehouse using the Polybase feature for fast parallel ingestion.